# Placing the last line first in each html <ul> with sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, text-formatting, html

I try to place the line "name: *****" just after the corresponding (innermost containing) "ul" each time an "ul" appears, so that it looks like this:

Before:

```
<ul>
   <ul>
      <li href="https://www.deepl.com/translator">DeepL</li>
      <li href="https://translate.google.com">Google Trad</li>
      name: "Translate",
   </ul>
   <li href="https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions">Youtube</li>
   <ul>
      <li href="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</li>
      <li href="https://twitter.com/">Twitter</li>
      <li href="https://www.instagram.com">Instagram</li>
      <li href="https://discordapp.com">Discord</li>
      name: "Network",
   </ul>
   name: "Fav",
</ul>
```

After:

```
<ul>
   name: "Fav",
   <ul>
      name: "Translate",
      <li href="https://www.deepl.com/translator">DeepL</li>
      <li href="https://translate.google.com">Google Trad</li>
   </ul>
   <li href="https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions">Youtube</li>
   <ul>
      name: "Network",
      <li href="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</li>
      <li href="https://twitter.com/">Twitter</li>
      <li href="https://www.instagram.com">Instagram</li>
      <li href="https://discordapp.com">Discord</li>
   </ul>
</ul>
```

So, I already tested a lot of things, like this:

```
sed -i -e 'N;s/<ul>\([.\n]*\)\n\(.*\),/\2\n\1' fav.html
```

This and all I found to now doesn't work because the "name" following the last "ul" is not always the one to replace. 
If anyone has an idea, I'd be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be impossible in `sed`. 
(The challenge has been issued; I await being proved wrong.) 
If you specifically require a `sed` solution,
you might as well stop reading this.

I was able to do it with a combination of `tac` and `awk`:

```
tac fav.html | awk '
    /<\/ul>/    { flag=1;            level++; }
    /<ul>/      { print save[level]; level--; }
    flag  &&  /name/    { flag=0; save[level] = $0; next; }
                { print; }
    ' | tac > fav.html.new  &&  mv fav.html.new fav.html
```

`tac fav.html` reverses `fav.html` on a line-by-line basis
(`tac` is `cat` spelled backwards) and so produces

```
</ul>
   name: "Fav",
   </ul>
      name: "Network",
      <li href="https://discordapp.com">Discord</li>
           ︙
   <ul>
    ︙
   <ul>
<ul>
```

The first two lines of the `awk` code count the `<ul>` nesting level. 
Since they are in reverse order, `</ul>` increases the level
and `<ul>` decreases it. 
When we see a `</ul>`, we set `flag` to indicate that
we are entering a `<ul>` block from the bottom. 
When we find a `name` near the bottom of a `<ul>` block, we save it,
and skip to the `next` line (without printing the `name` line). 
When we find a `<ul>` (i.e., the beginning of a `<ul>` block),
we print the saved `name` before we print the `<ul>` itself.

The final `tac` reverses the lines again,
putting most of them back where they were originally,
and putting each `name` *after* its corresponding `<ul>`.

Comment: No, the challenge comes from me. I thought it was possible via the sed with knowledge I probably didn't have.
But if this method exists, it suits me perfectly, as long as it does the job.

I've never used "tak" and "awk" before, so you're teaching me something.

So thanks for this !